# HTTP GET function with payload

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, ssjs

I am trying to send a HTTP Get Request with a payload in order to get a set of recommended images from client's external system. I am succsessful in doing so with postman. However, when I am trying to do the same in ssjs script, I do not get any response. Below is my function.

```
function getRecommendations(arrayofUsersNeedRecommendation, recommenderSettingsObj) {  
var status = [0];
var resp;
          var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(url);
          req.emptyContentHandling = 0;
          req.retries = 2;
          req.continueOnError = true;
          req.contentType = "text/plain";
          req.setHeader("x-client-id","somevalue");
          req.method = "GET"; 
          req.postData = arrayofUsersNeedRecommendation;
  try{
          resp = req.send();
  }
  catch(e)
  {
    Write(stringify(e));
  }
  var resultJSON = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(Stringify(resp.content));
    Write("Response"+(Stringify(resultJSON)));
      
};
```

POSTMAN REQUEST:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure this is a good idea? This link here says no, and I think I would agree: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body

Comment: So you mean, I should request my client's external team to use allow json paylod to the API and not plain text? Would that work?

Comment: Yeah, not a good idea. If you need a payload to be sent, you should shift it to another Method. Other option is to add parameters to the URL to store the info you need to pass

Comment: I do not have the option of passing the parameters in url. Also, why does the request works in postman but not in SSJS?

Comment: @SwatiMishra Most likely, Postman is automatically converting the GET to a POST. You cannot, by definition, have a body payload with a GET request, as that is in violation of the HTTP specifications, and any system that did accept a payload like that would be incompatible with virtually every HTTP library in the world (because, again, it's forbidden).